# what proper use of target pseudo class replace 'active' state on navigation on multiple pages?

Tags: html, css

Essentially, I have a micro site inside a large application. I wanted to create a tertiary navigation with an active state for pages. Its single html blob that gets inserted in multiple pages.

Ideally I would use an `active` class to highlight via which page in the tertiary navigation the user is on like below

```
  <nav>
   <ul>
   <li class="active"><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
```

But I have no control of the backend application and only have full control of `html, css` and want to avoid using solution with jquery detect url.

my css would be

```
 nav li:target {background:#ccc}
```

instead of

```
 nav li.active {background:#ccc}
```

I have seen it done kinda like this for `anchor` tags [like this](https://css-tricks.com/on-target/). 
The question is if its possible to do something like for different urls? what the proper usage of the `:target` class?

This below is what i have so far based on comments

```
  <nav>
   <ul>
   <li><a id="page1" href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
   <li><a id="page2" href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
   <li><a id="page3" href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

does not work across multiple pages? [here is a git working project](https://github.com/nolawi/anchor-target/)

Comment: Hm, the problem is that the `href`s in the `a`s can't point to the corresponding `li`s, right?

Comment: its not really the HTML fixed it, I actually can make the `active` class on the `anchor` i haven't built it yet but testing html doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to use the `target` class is backwards based on the example you provide above. Right now you are asking for the target class to highlight the link that is selected but the `target` pseudo class highlights the *content section* its associated with based on the link selected. If you view [w3schools site demo here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_target) you can see it in action. Notice that the content is change when the link is clicked, not vice versa.

If you want your navigation links to be highlighted based on the one selected you will need to dynamically add the 'active' class most likely using Jquery. Hope that helps.

**EDIT**

Based on our conversation I have looked through your code and was able to help fix it up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.content:target  {
   background: #ccc;
}
</style>
<body>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="page1.html#page1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html#page2">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.html#page3">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<h1>This is Page one</h1>

<div class="content" name="page1" id="page1">This is Page ONE paragraph</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You were applying an `ID`to the anchor tags when the nav links dont need an `ID` they need to have the `ID` *value* passed in the URL as `#page1`. Also your `target` CSS is the content section not the navigation menu. Follow this set up for the other pages and it should work great.

Comment: are you saying that :target should only be used for anchor links in the same page?

Comment: No. :target links can be used across multiple pages as long as you consistently use the same IDs and anchor names between pages.

Comment: thanks but it just doesn't seem to work across multiple pages.

Comment: In order to help you further I would have to see what code you are using. Not sure if you can create an example somewhere.

Comment: https://github.com/nolawi/testpage  here is a git test i have created- since fiddle can't do multiple pages

Comment: Updated my answer based on our conversation

Comment: cool i see where you were going - so it works for me if i do it this way ` <li><a id="page1" href="page1.html#page1">Page 1</a></li>` and doesnt work without an id as well. thanks

Comment: @nolawipetros you shouldnt have the same ID more than once on the page. In order for this to work in IE you need to add the name="page1" to the content section. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: you have to target the link though.. it doesnt seem to work like that

Answer (score 1):

See [§6.6.2. The target pseudo-class :target](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo)

> Some URIs refer to a location within a resource. This kind of URI ends
>   with a "number sign" (#) followed by an anchor identifier (called the
>   fragment identifier).
>
> URIs with fragment identifiers link to a certain element within the
>   document, known as the target element.
>
> A target element can be represented by the `:target` pseudo-class. If
>   the document's URI has no fragment identifier, then the document has
>   no target element.

So you can use

```css
 nav li:target {
   background: #ccc
 }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="page1"><a href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li id="page2"><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
    <li id="page3"><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks. I was hoping to see if this works across multiple pages though. -updated question

Comment: Doesn't it work for multiple pages? What's the problem?

Comment: i dont know if the target is suppose to work on refresh. and essentially the essence of this question is that